# Delete Asset In .exe File

Tags: exe

I finished making a game, so I started testing it, and me, being the person I am, have deleted my project file and assets, so all I have is my .exe file. Now, when I run my .exe file, I find that there's an image that I don't need and I want to delete it. I've tried using Resource Hacker and XM Resource Editor, but I wasn't able to find the file I wanted. I used Unity to make the project if that helps. I've tried doing open recent, and that hasn't worked either. Help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. This question is not on restoring my file, but removing the asset.

Comment: Find that project file or start a new project. Otherwise you can't get any help.

Comment: Unity does not store in-game assets as Win32 resources. If the asset is really embedded within the executable then you will need to rebuild your application with the extra content removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete an asset from game that you are running on a device? You can not remove it. That asset is now part of the binary that is your game.